# Find Three files of the Same Name but create with Different Applications

Tags: powershell, powershell-1.0

I am looking for a way to find three or more files of the same name but created with another application. Next action is then compare all three files to see if they were create on the same date and finaly compare that date against the current OS date.

Comment: What do you mean "created with another application"? For example, do you mean to say you have a file named "Foo" that was created by Word, Excel and Notepad - thus having file extensions foo.doc, foo.xls and foo.txt?

Answer (score 1):

As a partial answer, as I am not sure what you mean have the same name...

To see if files were created on the same date, you can just compare the CreationTime Property of each reference:

```
# Use Get-Item to retrieve FileInfo for two files
PS C:\> $a = Get-Item 'a.txt'
PS C:\> $b = Get-Item 'b.txt'
# Compare the DateTime field when they were created
PS C:\> $a.CreationDate -eq $b.CreationDate
False
# Compare just the 'Date' aspect of each file ignoring the time
PS C:\> $a.CreationDate.Date -eq $b.CreationDate.Date
True
```

You'll notice that Creation Date includes a time element, so unless they are truly the exact same you might not get the result you expected. To strip the time element out you simply add a .Date property to any DateTime field.

To compare against the operating system date and time:

```
# store the OS Date and Time for easier reference
PS C:\> $now = [DateTime]::Now
PS C:\> $today = [DateTime]::Today
# Compare using the stored values
PS C:\> $a.CreationDate.Date -eq $now
False
PS C:\> $a.CreationDate.Date -eq $today
True
```